# common_rosdeps missing in rosmake source install?

Tags: ros, installation, ros-groovy, source

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Now that groovy is [released](http://www.ros.org/wiki/groovy), I am trying to install from source and build on Debian.  Everything is working by going through the list, first installing the missing debs from the [ubuntu repository](http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu/pool/), but downloading from source from there.  I got through the **wet** part of the install (section 2.1) and am building the **dry** packages now (section 2.2), and there seems to be a problem with dependencies.  Many of the packages are depending on the stack or package of `common_rosdeps`, which is not a package or stack anymore (and wasn't in *Fuerte* either, according to the [common_rosdeps wiki page](http://ros.org/wiki/common_rosdeps).

I am currently solving this problem by commenting out the dependency in the `manifest.xml` manually, but this workaround isn't desired, I wish I could just follow the instructions.

**Is there some step or dependency which is missing for rosdep to find common_rosdeps for the dry packages?**

The error that I am getting is similar to this on all the packages depending on common_rosdeps:

```
{-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  mkdir -p bin
  cd build && cmake -Wdev -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=/home/jamuraa/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated/share/ros/core/rosbuild/rostoolchain.cmake  ..
  -- The C compiler identification is GNU 4.7.2
  -- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 4.7.2
  -- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/gcc
  -- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/gcc -- works
  -- Detecting C compiler ABI info
  -- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
  -- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++
  -- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ -- works
  -- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
  -- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
  -- Found PythonInterp: /usr/bin/python (found version "2.7.3") 
  [rosbuild] Building package carrot_planner
  Failed to invoke /home/jamuraa/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated/bin/rospack deps-manifests carrot_planner
  [rospack] Error: package/stack 'base_local_planner' depends on non-existent package 'common_rosdeps' and rosdep claims that it is not a system dependency. Check the ROS_PACKAGE_PATH or try calling 'rosdep update'
  
  
  CMake Error at /home/jamuraa/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated/share/ros/core/rosbuild/public.cmake:129 (message):
    
  
    Failed to invoke rospack to get compile flags for package 'carrot_planner'.
    Look above for errors from rospack itself.  Aborting.  Please fix the
    broken dependency!
  
  Call Stack (most recent call first):
    /home/jamuraa/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated/share/ros/core/rosbuild/public.cmake:203 (rosbuild_invoke_rospack)
    CMakeLists.txt:12 (rosbuild_init)
  
  
  -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/51343/common_rosdeps-missing-in-rosmake-source-install?/) by [jamuraa](https://answers.ros.org/users/534/jamuraa/) on ROS Answers with karma: 218 on 2013-01-02

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

See https://github.com/ros-planning/navigation/issues/17
Sorry, the maintainer might be on holidays, so it can take a couple of days before this gets fixed. In the meantime you can fix the sources yourself, by just removing the dependency.

---

Originally posted by [KruseT](https://answers.ros.org/users/888/kruset/) with karma: 7848 on 2013-01-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jamuraa](https://answers.ros.org/users/534/jamuraa/) on 2013-01-03**:
Thanks, I thought I was going weird.  I might make a pull request for that later, since I just did it all this morning.

**Comment by [jamuraa](https://answers.ros.org/users/534/jamuraa/) on 2013-01-03**:
Thanks, I thought I was going weird.